# outputStream write, как записать в текст в файл

Tags: java, файлы

Добрый день,

Есть код, циклически пробигаем по элементам строки из файла.

Вопрос: Как записать выбраные элементы в другой файл?

```
InputStream istr = new FileInputStream("Path\\A.txt");
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Path\\B.txt");  
int isize = istr.available();

for (int b = 0; b < isize; b++) 
{
    out.write**(b)** // Как правильно записать "b" в файл ?
    if (b % 5 == 0)
    istr.skip(b+5);
}
```

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович [Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих в поисковик](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2013/). Если вы видели аналогичный вопрос на сайте, пожалуйста, закройте этот вопрос как дубликат к ранее заданному.

Comment: я не просто видел, а лично на него отвечал. я же не в гугл отправляю. просто сказал, что такая информация уже имеется, полагаю, что если человек заинтересован, то найти это не составляет труда...

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович Пожалуйста, в этом случае, закройте данный вопрос как дубликат предыдущего. Буду рад вам в этом помочь!

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать так:

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("output.txt"))) {
        Files
            //построчно читаем каждую строку
            .lines(Paths.get("input.txt"))
            //разбиваем строку на символы, составляем из них пару <index,symbol>
            .flatMap(e -> {
                AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(-1);
                return Stream
                         .generate(() -> 
                                       new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
                                                index.incrementAndGet(), 
                                                e.charAt(index.get())))
                         .limit(e.length());
            })
            //выбираем только пары с индексом кратным 5
            .filter(e -> e.getKey() % 5 == 0)
            //избавляемся от индекса
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            //записываем в файл
            .forEach(e -> {
                    try {
                        writer.write(e);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
             });
    }
```